# Is there any way we can unlock an android phone or retrieve the lost pattern?

Tags: lock-screens

I forgot my screen lock pattern. As I restarted the phone the face lock is not being accepted.
Is there any way I can unlock it or retrieve the pattern without losing my data.

*it is the new version of android so there is nothing like forgot password*

Thanks

Comment: `If you can't unlock your phone, you'll need to erase it.` https://support.google.com/android/answer/7663172

Comment: what phone model? bootloader was unlocked previously?